# urxvt bold colors are wrong - bold #0-7 are using colors from #8-15

Tags: terminal, urxvt

My colors are off. Specifically, the bold version of colors 1-6 is broken:

[image]

The color of each (emboldened) index should match the color of the text beside it. It does not.

This is generated from [this](https://gist.github.com/1047767) gist, modified to include colors #0-15. (It's identical except the `, 16` on line 25 is removed.)

**Update:**

Here's what's going on: Bold #1 is using color #9, bold #2 is using color #10 and so on. I confirmed this by changing `color9`, `color10`, etc. in my `.Xresources` file.

I'm using [solarized](https://github.com/altercation/solarized/blob/master/xresources-colors-solarized/Xresources) `.Xresources` and would rather keep colors #9-15 colored differently.

Furthermore, the bold colors are correct in xterm.

Why is urxvt Bold #0-7 using colors from #8-15, and how do I stop this?

Comment: Can you share your version of the script? It'd be helpful to see exactly what escape sequences you're sending.  (e.g. intense vs. bold)

Comment: It's literally exactly the same, except the ", 16" on line 25 is removed.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use the `+is` commandline flag, or (exactly equivalently), set the `intensityStyles` resource to false.  From the man page:

> intensityStyles: boolean
>
> When font styles are not enabled, or this option is enabled (True,
>   option -is, the default), bold/blink font styles imply high intensity
>   foreground/background colours. Disabling this option (False, option
>   +is) disables this behaviour, the high intensity colours are not reachable.

So, in `.Xresources`:

```
URxvt.intensityStyles: false
```

It's not clear which behavior is "right".  (I prefer "bold" = "bold font".)  Historically, some terminals treat SGR 1 ( \e[1m ) as "bold", and others treat it as "intense".  Current terminals exhibit a mix of behaviors.  Top row in each window is colors 0 through 15 in "bold".  Second row is without "bold".  (`-bdc` and `+bdc` is the XTerm equivalent of URxvt's `-is` and `+is` -- not sure why it only appears to affect color 0 on my system)

[image: various terminals' treatment of bold vs intense]

[script to run the terminals in this image](https://gist.github.com/4173926)

Comment: Wow, terminal emulators really are a ghetto. Thank you very much, this was bugging the hell out of me.

Comment: It's `xterm +/-pc` (and not `+/-bdc`) that is equivalent to `urxvt +/-is`. "not sure why it only appears to affect color 0" – because you used the wrong option :-) I could fix your post but I don't feel like retaking the screenshots :-)

Comment: On a side note, GNOME Terminal 3.32 / VTE 0.56 switched its default to "bold only", equivalent to `xterm +pc` and `urxvt +is`.