# Error highlight in Vim makes text unreadable

Tags: terminal, vim, colors, themes, solarized

So I have a NeoVim setup I made a long time ago. A friend convinced me that the Solarized terminal theme was awesome and so I have that configured, not sure if I have a matching Vim theme.

Anyhow, when I started using Rust and C++, the compiler warnings were highlighted in the same color as the text. This was mostly for unused imports and the like, so I didn't bother much. However recently it got very much in my way when looking at C code.

This is the situation:

[image: screenshot]

(The line reads `use std::io;`, but the font color matches the highlight.)

So my question is if anyone knows how to edit the highlight color? I don't remember where I setup the theme, I think it might be in `~/.Xresources`:

```
Xft.dpi: 104
Xft.antialias: true
Xft.hinting: true
Xft.rgba: rgb
Xft.hintstyle: hintfull Xcursor.size: 40

URxvt.termName: xterm-256color
URxvt.font: xft:DejaVu Sans Mono:pixelsize=24
URxvt.scrollBar: false
URxvt.scrollStyle: rxvt
URxvt.internalBorder: 20
URxvt.letterSpace: -2
URxvt.iso14755: False  
URxvt.iso14755_52: False

#define S_base03        #002b36
#define S_base02        #073642
#define S_base01        #586e75
#define S_base00        #657b83
#define S_base0         #839496
#define S_base1         #93a1a1
#define S_base2         #eee8d5
#define S_base3         #fdf6e3

*background:            S_base03
*foreground:            S_base0
*fadeColor:             S_base03
*cursorColor:           S_base1
*pointerColorBackground:S_base01
*pointerColorForeground:S_base1

#define S_yellow        #b58900
#define S_orange        #cb4b16
#define S_red           #dc322f
#define S_magenta       #d33682
#define S_violet        #6c71c4
#define S_blue          #268bd2
#define S_cyan          #2aa198
#define S_green         #859900

!! black dark/light
*color0:                S_base02
*color8:                S_base03

!! red dark/light
*color1:                S_red
*color9:                S_orange

!! green dark/light
*color2:                S_green
*color10:               S_base01

!! yellow dark/light
*color3:                S_yellow
*color11:               S_base00

!! blue dark/light
*color4:                S_blue
*color12:               S_base0

!! magenta dark/light
*color5:                S_magenta
*color13:               S_violet

!! cyan dark/light
*color6:                S_cyan
*color14:               S_base1

!! white dark/light
*color7:                S_base2
*color15: S_base3
```

Comment: "not sure if I have a matching Vim theme" – Probably not, at least the light blue of "std" seems to come from the 256-color palette. For Solarized you'll need a Vim color scheme that uses 16 colors only, and was designed for Solarized in particular.

Comment: You'll also need to make sure that urxvt doesn't tamper with the colors when bold is requested, see https://superuser.com/q/512138.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Solarized, you need to configure it in *both* your terminal emulator *and* Vim (also, most of every other application that wants to seriously use terminal colors.)

For Vim, you can get the Solarized colorscheme from the [altercation/vim-colors-solarized](https://github.com/altercation/vim-colors-solarized) repository.

Follow the instructions on the README file in that repository, or if you already use a plug-in manager, use that to install that plug-in.

Make sure you're adding this line to your `.vimrc`:

```
colorscheme solarized
```

(You might want to explicitly set `'background'` as well, to "dark" or "light", though Vim is usually pretty good at figuring that out from your terminal background color.)